# Подключение через прокси-сервер проходит не ко всем ресурсам

Tags: java, android, прокси

Тестирую работу прокси-серверов, подключаясь через них к различным URL адресам.
К примеру прокси-сервер `216.171.41.43:45554` (Socks5) для следующих адресов:

- `https://google.com`
- `https://youtube.com`

в момент получения стрима

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
```

вываливается с ошибкой

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

и ни в какую не дает получить код страницы. При всем при этом адреса:

- `https://ya.ru`
- `https://www.yahoo.com/`

работают нормально. Кстати если указать `https://yahoo.com/` (без `www`) получение стрима вывалится с той же ошибкой.

Сам коннект для всех адресов проходит почти с первой попытки:

```
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress(ip, port))).connect();
```

Подскажите, с чем может быть связана такая работа прокси-серверов? Почему получается соединится с нужным ресурсом, но не получается получить код страницы?

---

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("https://www.yahoo.com/");
    String ip = "216.171.41.43";
    int port = 45554;
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress(ip, port)));
    conn.setConnectTimeout(2000);
    BufferedReader in = null;

    while (true) {
        try {
            conn.connect();
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
```

Comment: Потому что прокси-сервер так настроен, например.

Comment: @Roman Была мысль, что адрес прокси-сервера находится в "черном списке" у ресурса, сейчас пришел к выводу, что это не так. Каким образом можно заранее понять, подойдет ли прокси-сервер для обращения к  ресурсу? В чем может заключаться настройка, о которой вы говорите?